# Retrieve the selected values from a page loaded in jQuery Dialog

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to retrieve the selected values from a page that has been loaded via jQuery Dialog.

Following are the details - Once the 'SelectTeam.php' page has been loaded on to the Dialog (have passed some default selection), Once the user clicks on the 'OK' button of the dialog I want to retrieve the new selection as the user can override the default selection & then press OK. How should I get new selection on pressing the 'OK' button.

Parent Page -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog Example</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
    <style>
            body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openDialog(url) {
           $("#somediv").load(url).dialog({
                                            modal:true,
                                            title: 'Team Select',
                                            width: 300,
                                            height: 400,
                                            autoOpen: true,
                                            resizable: false,
                                            buttons: {
                                                "OK": function() {
                                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                                },
                                                "Cancel": function() {
                                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                                }
                                            }
                                            });
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="somediv"></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="openDialog('SelectTeam.php?TeamIds=2,4,13');">Dialog</a>
</body>
   </html>
```

Child Page that is loaded in jQuery Dialog -

```
 <?php

$lstTeamId = array();

if (isset($_GET['TeamIds']))
{
$lstTeamId = explode(',', $_GET['TeamIds']);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="frmSelectTeams">

        <table width="100%" border="1">
             <tr>
                <th align="center"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/></th>
                <th align="center">Team Name</th>
             </tr>

            <?php
            for ($index = 1; $index < 21; $index++)
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="test" name="chk' . $index . '" '; if (in_array ($index, $lstTeamId)) { echo 'checked="checked"';} echo ' /></td>';
                echo '<td align="center">Team ' . $index . '</td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>

        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your checkboxes should be radio buttons, if you only want one selection...? And they should have values equal to what you want to select, namely the new selection url?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just call openDialog(url) again, with the url of the new selection?

```
buttons: {
   "OK":      function() 
                new_url = 'new_selection_url';
                openDialog(new_url);
              },
   "Cancel": function() {
               $(this).dialog("close");
             }
}
```

EDIT: I'm not too sure wher you want the selections to be displayed.  Must the new selection be in the dialog? Outside the dialog?

UPDATE: OK, looks like you want to load it into #somediv.  Just call load again:

```
buttons: {
   "OK":      function() 
                new_url = 'new_selection_url';
                $('#somediv').load(new_url);
              },
```

UPDATE: If you want only one url to be selected, you must use radio buttons instead.   To get the values of all the selected checkboxes, you can try something like this:

```
var urls = [];
$('.test :checked').each(function() {
   urls.push($(this).val());
 });
new_url = urls[0];
```

If you replace the checkboxes with radio buttons, you can try something like this:

```
new_url = $('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#frmSelectTeams').val()
```